# $\sin (y-30^{\circ})=\cos y, 0^{\circ}\leq y \leq360^{\circ}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given that $$\sin (y-30^{\circ})=\cos y, 0^{\circ}\leq y \leq360^{\circ}$$

My attempt,

$\sin y \cos(-30^{\circ})-\cos y \sin (-30^{\circ})=\cos y$

$\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin y+\frac{1}{2}\cos y=\cos y$

$\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin y=\frac{1}{2}\cos y$

$\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\tan y=\frac{1}{2}$

$\tan y=\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}$

$y=30^{\circ},210^{\circ}$

But the answers are incorrect. Anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: There is a typo : $\frac{\color{red}{\sqrt3}}{2}\tan y=\frac{1}{2}$, corrected

Comment: What answer is given there in your book?

Comment: 60 degree and 240 degree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is , you expanded :

> $$\sin(A-B)=\sin(A)\cos(-B)-\cos(A)\sin(-B)$$

Which is definitely wrong

You either expand it as :
 $$\sin(A-B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)-\cos(A)\sin(B)$$ or  $$\sin(A-B)=\sin(A)\cos(-B)+\cos(A)\sin(-B)$$

But not both simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

It's much simpler to turn the sine into a cosine using the formulae for complementary angles:

$\sin(y-30)=\cos(90-(y-30))=\cos(120-y)$, so you have  to solve the simpler equation:
$$\cos(120-y)=\cos y.$$

Comment: OP is asking `Anything wrong with my solution ?` not any alternate way.

Comment: The answer could have started with "avoid expansion & use $$\sin(90^\circ-y)=\cos y$$  or $$\cos(90^\circ-y)=\sin y$$"

Comment: @Iab bhattacharjee: You're right. I'll fix that.